# Debian installed kernel not shown in GRUB

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, grub2

On Debian (Jessie) 8 I added the [backports source](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) and installed a newer kernel via:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -t jessie-backports linux-image-amd64
```

I then ran

```
update-grub
```

However on reboot I do not see an option in GRUB to select the new kernel and the usual option loads the existing kernel:

```
uname -r
3.16.0-4-amd64
```

Firstly can I just update the kernel like this without recompiling all the software? (I want a new kernel in the hope it supports my hardware)

Second, if so, how do I make it appear in GRUB?

Comment: `update-grub` only updates the grub files that are used to build the grub configuration. You forgot to do `grub-install`, most common is `grub-install /dev/sda`. Make sure you are using kernel 4.7 from the backports.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro thanks - that put the entry in GRUB :) When I choose it I just get a black screen so it seems I haven't done the upgrade correctly (pressing power off does gracefully power off).

Comment: It was the graphics driver, if I booted with `nomodeset` (by pressing `e` on the Debian option and adding `nomodeset` in the end of the line starting `linux`) then I got a Desktop as expected. If you want to post your answer I will accept it.

Comment: all of this should be handeld automagicaly by the package manager (apt-get) ? I've never had to update grub manually when installing kernel from debian repository ....

Comment: @Mali I had to update grub because of my video card. Once I booted successfully in to the desktop for the first time all was well. I'm guessing the desktop was using the wrong videomode initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, expecting `update-grub` to work and create the `grub` boot-time tidbits is a common mistake I also made as a rookie.

`update-grub` only updates the grub files that are used to boot the grub configuration.

You have to do `grub-install` ; the most common of reinstalling/fixing grub is:

From [Grub2/Installing - Post-Restoration Commands](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)

> To refresh the available devices and settings in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> To look for the bootloader location.
>
> ```
> grub-probe -t device /boot/grub
> ```
>
> To install GRUB 2 to the sdX drive's MBR or boot sector (sda, sdb,
>   etc.)
>
> ```
> sudo grub-install /dev/sda
> ```

Since you are installing from the Debian backports, make sure you are using the latest kernel, which should be at the time of this post kernel 4.7.

Comment: `grub-probe` is a nice tip.